# Ищу аналог TMSFMXGrid для Delphi 10 взамен стандартного Grida?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, поиск-библиотек, grid

Если ли бесплатные пакеты с удобными гридами, аналог TMSFMXGrid для Delphi 10 взамен стандартного Grida? Нужно чтоб можно было объединять ячейки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем пришлось перерисовывать самому стандартный грид.

Объединение получилось обыграть по другому (просто значение ячейки присваивался текст с символом переноса StringGrid1.Cells[2,0] := 'Текст 1'#13#10'Чуть ниже текст';).

А вот самое главное было выравнивание значение ячеек по центрам вертикали и горизонтали и переносом текста по словам, которое не влазит(!).

```
    //отрисовываем вручную стрингрид
procedure TTabbedForm.StringGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
const
   HorzTextMargin = 2;
   VertTextMargin = 1;
var
   TextLayout : TTextLayout;
   TextRect: TRectF;
begin
  { if (Column.Index=2) then
   begin}
      TextRect := Bounds;
      TextRect.Inflate(-HorzTextMargin, -VertTextMargin);
      // RectF'ом мы закрашиваем рамку фокуса на гриде при клике
      Canvas.FillRect(RectF(Bounds.Left-3,Bounds.Top-3,Bounds.Right+3,Bounds.Bottom+3), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);
      TextLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
      try
         TextLayout.BeginUpdate;
         try
            TextLayout.WordWrap := True; // True for Multiline text
            TextLayout.Opacity := Column.AbsoluteOpacity;
            TextLayout.HorizontalAlign := StringGrid1.TextSettings.HorzAlign;
            TextLayout.VerticalAlign := StringGrid1.TextSettings.VertAlign;
            TextLayout.Trimming := TTextTrimming.Character;
            TextLayout.TopLeft := TextRect.TopLeft;
            TextLayout.Text := Value.ToString;
            TextLayout.MaxSize := PointF(TextRect.Width, TextRect.Height);

            { Custom settings rendering }
            //TextLayout.Font.Family := 'Times New Roman';
            TextLayout.Font.Style := [];
            TextLayout.Font.Size := 11;
            TextLayout.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
         finally
            TextLayout.EndUpdate;
         end;
         TextLayout.RenderLayout(Canvas);
      finally
         TextLayout.Free;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Было бы круто, если бы привели в ответе получившийся код - наверняка кому-то в будущем пригодится)

Comment: Готово, теперь круто)